# Is there any standard for where data is located in a C union?

Tags: c, arrays, simd, unions

I have the following union:

```
union problem {
    int i;
    int *v;
};
```

On my system the `int` is 4 bytes while the `int*` is 8. I have an array of say 10 of these structures. In a certain section of code I happen to know that all of the members of the array are using the `int` of the union. I need to copy these ints into an array of ints. Now if the source array was an int array i could use `memcpy` to quickly copy the data.

Is there any guarantee that the int is stored in the low or high memory of the union? I'd like to be able to copy the data without iterating so I was thinking of looping through with SIMD and a shuffle. To do that I would have to know where the int actually is within the union and I'm guessing that is implementation specific.

Comment: No there is no guarantee from the C specification. This is a union which means the member `i` and the member `v` both start at the same memory location.  How large the total size of `problem` is will depend on the largest size of any of the union members plus any padding done.  `memcpy()` has its uses but this is not one of them.  best to iterate through the array and assign each one.  also doing a `memcpy()` is iterating over the memory area as well.

Comment: I am curious why you would want to optimize the copying of a particular member of an array of a union when the array is only 10 or so elements and a simple loop would solve the problem and you could move on to something else.

Comment: @RichardChambers: There is a guarantee about *where* the members are stored within the representation of the union, just not how the bits of the `int` and pointer correspond in terms of values.

Comment: @RichardChambers The 10 is just an example because it doesn't really matter for discussion. But in practice it's a series of 100-20000 arrays between 20 and 200 in length. It may be worth going back and rewriting the structures to avoid unions and add more fields to the other structures. The union choice was an early design decision to cut down on logic or something (it seemed reasonable at the time). It now seems ill advised.

Comment: @R.. I do not see the difference between what you write and what I wrote. The general rule is you know where they start and after that all you really can count on is that any area of memory allocated for the union, whether on the stack or on the heap or where ever will be large enough to contain any particular member of the union.   I have seen plenty of errors arising from people assuming that they can count on particular alignments especially with unions involving structs where the member alignment was not specified explicitly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both elements of the union are stored with their first byte at the starting address of the union.  In your example, both the `int` and the `int *` are stored starting at the same address.  This is always guaranteed.

What is not defined is whether the `int` is stored over the less significant or more significant bytes of the `int *`.  Note that if you have an array of the union, copying the elements wholesale into an array of `int` will copy indeterminate values into every alternate member of the target array (in practice; it's probably strictly undefined behaviour in theory).

Consequently, to copy the ten `int` values from your array of ten `union problem`, you'd need to iterate over the elements of the array, copying the `.i` members in turn.

```
union problem p[10] = { … };
int copy[10];
```

Either:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    copy[i] = p[i].i;
```

Or:

```
int *cp = copy;
union problem *pp = p;
int *end = copy + 10;
while (cp < end)
    *cp++ = (*pp++).i;
```

Comment: so in terms of efficiently copying I'm not likely to do better than a loop over the `foo.i`?

Comment: Correct; you're unlikely to do better than copying with a loop.